# Books for mixed distributions (continuous and discrete)?

Tags: references, continuous-data, discrete-data, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

What is a good book that covers mixed distributions?

Most statistics books either only briefly mention them or do not cover the topic at all.

I'd like to have a comprehensive resource covering issues of joint distributions with both discrete and continuous variables, conditional and marginal distributions in the mixed case, etc.

Comment: Check out a related question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/8570/2660. All of the books listed discuss joint distributions.

Comment: Interesting, I'll certainly look into the list. Thanks!

Comment: Any application in mind?